# Refreshing on checkout page empties cart and redirects

Tags: add-on, cartthrob

I know why it's redirecting (b/c the cart is empty) but I'm not sure why refreshing on the checkout page is causing the cart to be emptied. Any idea? Latest install of all of the above, just upgraded.

Comment: Can you add some more details please - relevant snippets of your template, what you've tried so far, exact steps to reproduce etc...

Comment: Seemed to be an issue with our custom shipping module. Resolved.

Comment: Awesome. If possible can you post a quick write up of your solution in the answer box below (or what was causing it) so it may help others in future?

Answer (score 1):

The question poster added a comment with the resolution... I'm posting it here as an answer:

**"Seemed to be an issue with our custom shipping module. Resolved"**